# scanning for next empty value in a 2d array and replacing values in the row

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

So basically, I need to search for the next empty value of an index (which is designated as 0), and replace the whole row with a variety of information. for instance, if there is a blank element in the third row, instead of "0, 0, 0 ,0" it will be "(row number), a, b, c". This is what i have so far and i just get a long line of run-time errors

```
String[][] clientsArray = new String[20][4];
int rows = 20;
int columns = 4;

for (int r = 0; r < rows ; r++ )
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns ; c++ )
            {
                if (clientsArray[r][c].equals ("0"))
                {
                    String key = Integer.toString(r);
                    clientsArray[r][0] = key;
                    clientsArray[r][0+1] = "a"
                    clientsArray[r][0+2] = "b"
                    clientsArray[r][0+3] = "c"
                    break;
                }
             }
    }
```

At the moment, the whole 2d array is filled with '0's, I just haven't included that section of code.

**note: i have changed the values which were 'c' to 0

Comment: For starters you actually have 20 "rows", each with "4" columns. At least the way you declared `clientsArray`. When you fix this, if `c` is anything but zero, what do you think would happen when you use e.g. `c+3` as index?

Comment: this is what i was going for. When it searches for the row beginning with 0, it will replace the first column of that row, with the row number, and then the second column with 'a', third with 'b' and fourth with 'c'

Comment: For that you don't need the inner loop.

Comment: omg. this is killing me. cheers buddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the comments, you are looking to:

1. search through a 2D array, looking for the first row whose 1st column is "0".
2. Then you want to replace every element in that row.

   ```
   String[][] clientsArray = new String[20][4];
   int rows = 20; // this can also be clientsArray.length
   int columns = 4; // this can also be clientsArray[0].length

   for (int r = 0; r < rows ; r++ )
   {
       //since you are only looking at the 1st column, you don't need the inner loop
          // this makes sure that the spot in the 2d array is set, otherwise trying to call .equals will crash your program.
          if (clientsArray[r][0] == null || clientsArray[r][0].equals ("0")) 
          {
             String key = Integer.toString(r);
             clientsArray[r][0] = key;
             clientsArray[r][1] = "a"
             clientsArray[r][2] = "b"
             clientsArray[r][3] = "c"   //you don't need the 0+, if you wanted to have a 2d array with more then 4 rows, you could put a for loop here insead of doing it 4 times like you did here
             break; //if you wanted to find ALL empty rows take this out.
             //also note if you have 2 loops like in your question, if would only break out of the 1st one
          }   
   }
   ```